# sql error Type_mismatch 80 in Select Count(1) query

Tags: mysql

Morning everyone, I've been looking at this error for days. It's really silly, it always worked. I'm moving my website to another server with a newer MySQL and what always worked (a page count, that displays pages with 20 lines at a time) gives an error in every page.
I ran out of ideas, I'd be grateful if someone has some ideas to give me.
Here's the code where the error should be:

```
56 SQL = "SELECT Count(1) AS TotalCount FROM Table1,Table2 WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.abc AND Table1.def > 0"
57 conn.Open DSNtemp
58 Set rs = conn.Execute(SQL)
59 PageCount = ((rs("TotalCount") - 1) \ 20) + 1
60 conn.Close
```

this is the error:
/page.asp |59|800a000d|Type_mismatch 80

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Table1.ID and Table2.abc are both int(11), Table1.def is a smallint(6), and they all have numbers in those columns. Also, when run in phpmyadmin that query gives 15 as a result, so it gives no error and a number comes out. It really makes no sense...

Comment: ((rs("TotalCount") - 1) \ 20) + 1  you are mixing numbers with objects rs("TotalCount")  this can't be good.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Excuse me I'm not sure I understood, isn't TotalCount the result of that query? How do I call for that result then?

Comment: rs("TotalCount") isn't a number so you have to convert it, besides what are you using asp net asp

Comment: I am using classic asp

Comment: then use CInt(rs("TotalCount"))

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, unfortunately the error remains and is still the same.

Comment: no problem, could you  try SELECT Count(*) AS TotalCount FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.abc WHERE  t1.def > 0;  your comma sepreated table are old style i mean really old. if this also doesn't work, and i am pretty sure it won'rt eiter,  you have to show the content of DSNtemp

Answer (score 0):

Without more info is difficult to say which is the problem.
By the select, I would check that

Table1.ID = Table2.abc  --> are both same column type? if Table1.ID it's a number and Table2.abc is a string, is this field always filled with a number?

Table1.def --> is this field always a number? if it finds any '' a string 'xx' or a null perhaps it may crash.

Hope it helps!!